# Define the notion of "pairs" using higher-order logic

Tags: functional-programming, logic, lambda-calculus, church-encoding

Revising for a course on automated reasoning and I don't quite understand how to answer this question:

Show how the notion of pairs `(x, y)` can be defined in higher-order logic using a lambda abstraction. Define a function π1 that returns the first element of such a pair. Finally, show that `π1(x, y) = x.`

I've found similar questions on stackoverflow, but they're all to do with scheme, which I've never used. An explanation in English/relevant mathematical notation would be appreciated

Comment: Here is some runnable code for your favorite browser (I use the `Number` type for sake of simplicity): `const Pair = (x, y) => f => f(x, y); const fst = pair => pair((x, y) => x); fst(Pair(2, 3)) === 2;` yields `true`

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```
PAIR := λx. λy. λp. p x y

π1 := λp. p (λx. λy. x)

π2 := λp. p (λx. λy. y)

π1 (PAIR a b) => a

π2 (PAIR a b) => b
```

Check the wiki entry on [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Church_pairs) for some good examples, too

Answer (score 2):

The main topic of this question is to understand how data can be represented as functions. When you're working with other paradigms , the normal way of thinking is "data = something that's stored in a variable" (could be an array, object, whatever structure you want).

But when we're in functional programming, we can also represent data as functions.
So let's say you want a function pair(x,y)

This is "pseudo" lisp language:

```
(function pair x y = 
   lambda(pick) 
      if pick = 1 return x 
      else return y  )
```

That example, is showing a function that returns a lambda function which expects a parameter.

```
(function pi this-is-pair = this-is-pair 1)
```

this-is-pair should be constructed with a pair function, therefore, the parameter is a function which expects other parameter (pick).

And now, you can test what you need

```
(pi (pair x y ) ) should return x
```

I would highly recommend you to see this video about [compound data](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/video-lectures/2b-compound-data/). Most of the examples are made on lisp, but it's great to understand a concept like that.

Answer (score 0):

Pairs or tuples describes Products Domain, is the union of all elements of the set A and all elements of the set B:

```
A × B = { (a, b) | a ∈ A, b ∈ B }
```

Here, A and B are diferent types, so if you for example are in a laguage program like C, Java, you can have pair like `(String, Integer)`, `(Char, Boolean)`, `(Double, Double)`

Now, the function π1, is just a function that takes a pair and returns the first element, this function is called in usually `first`, and that's how it looks like `π1(x, y) = x`, on the other hand you have second, doing the same thing but returning the second element:

```
fst(a, b) = a
snd(a, b) = b
```

When I studied the signature *"Characteristics of the programming languages"* in college our professor recommended this **[book](https://staffweb.worc.ac.uk/DrC/Courses%202005-6/Comp%204070/Reading%20Materials/book%5B1%5D.pdf),** see the chapter **Product Domain** to understand well all this concepts.